# php access all global variables from inside a function

Tags: php, global-variables, scope

I have many global variables in a php program. For some reason, I need a function to be able to access many or all the global variables. Is there any quick way (don't need to name them one by one such as   global var1,var2,var3,car4,........; ) 
to declare a function to access all global variables ?

Comment: _(Yes, I'm an evil man because of giving hint)_ Just use `$GLOBALS` from inside function

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 2):

PHP's super global $GLOBALS may be what you are looking for.
More information about Super globals can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and for more info about $GLOBALS: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php